# Fordward incoming RDP (Port 3389) communication to LAN machine

Tags: iptables

No traffic will be external (Internet Facing) all traffic will be internal.

What I'm trying to achieve is to RDP from the WINDOWS PC 1, have the RDP traffic from the WINDOWS PC 1 masquerade as the Linux SERVERS IP address (10.0.2.5) and from there continue to the destination WINDOWS PC 2.

Here's a picture to illustrate further:

```
    WINDOWS PC 1 (10.0.2.122)
             |
           [RDP]
             |
             V
 LINUX SERVER (10.0.2.5)
             |
         [FW 3389]
             |
             V
   WINDOWS PC 2 (10.0.2.188)
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

- I've enabled port forwarding in the kernel: `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- I've tried several answers already from many forums, still no go:

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to 10.0.2.188:3389`
`iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 3389 -d 10.0.2.188 -j ACCEPT`

- I watched the iptables counters and see no activity:`watch 'iptables -vL'`

Comment: Have you got an unusual subnet mask? If not, what's stopping you going straight from PC1 `10.0.2.122` to PC2 `10.0.2.188`?

Comment: Wait. You have the same subnet mask on your hosts? If this is true, there is no even routing happening, just some bridge forwarding...(if those hosts are connected on different nics of your Linux server) or, they are talking to each other directly, if they are on the same hub...And in this scenario, your "Linux firewall" isn't even the problem here...

Comment: @nwilder with `MASQUERADE` it could work.

Comment: @roaima I'm trying to masquerade as 10.0.2.5 from WINDOWS PC 1. I do not want to go directly. But you're right, everything is /24 nothing weird here.

Comment: @nwildner WINDOWS PC1 and PC 2 are not directly connected (via NICs) to the LInux Server.  They are on the same switch.

Comment: See my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Well after reading your comment, it seems that those 2 PCs are part of the same [Local Area Network(LAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network). This is the reason why you cannot see traffic from your Linux Box.

[This tutorial](http://computer.howstuffworks.com/lan-switch1.htm) will teach you the basics of LAN, but making it straightforward:

- Those computers will know each other through [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol);
- They will "see" that they belong to the same lan and will talk directly
- If your Linux box is the gateway, it will only be used to route traffic that DOES NOT belong to that lan(out of `10.0.2.0/24` or whatever mask you have defined)

**tl,dr**: Those computers are on the same LAN so, to see some traffic from your Linux box(and you will not be able to "intercept/mangle", just see") you will have to put your Linux nic on promisc mode: `ip link set dev eth0 promisc on`

Ok. Passing all this theoric stuff, when you are making a `DNAT` inside the same lan, you will have to make the packet BACK to it's origins "forcefully" using a SNAT. This is a special case where you have 2 computers on the same LAN while doing a NAT.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3389 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.2.188:3389
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.2.188 --dport 3389 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.2.122
```

This way you will enforce that, when a packet comes back to your Linux box, a Source nat will be done to `10.0.2.122`

**Other Alternatives:**

Make a [RDP proxy with HA-proxy](https://linuxcluster.wordpress.com/2014/10/09/deploying-haproxy-1-4-24-to-load-balance-ms-terminal-services-on-centos-6/) and put those hosts on separated networks. This is an overkill(creating a single member rdp proxy balance) but it is an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

#### HAProxy solution

Cf. [Microsoft Remote Desktop Services (RDS) Load-Balancing](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/microsoft-remote-desktop-services-rds-load-balancing/)

```bash
sudo apt install haproxy

cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
frontend ft_rdp
    mode tcp
    bind :3389 name rdp
    timeout client 1h
    log global
    option tcplog
    tcp-request inspect-delay 2s
    tcp-request content accept if RDP_COOKIE
    default_backend bk_rdp

backend bk_rdp
    mode tcp
    balance leastconn
    persist rdp-cookie
    timeout server 1h
    timeout connect 4s
    log global
    option tcp-check
    tcp-check connect port 3389 ssl
    default-server inter 3s rise 2 fall 3
    server windows_pc_2 10.0.2.188:3389 weight 10 verify none
EOF

sudo systemctl restart haproxy
systemctl list-units | grep haproxy
```